# Is it possible to create a particle with isospin 0 and charge -2?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Is it possible to create a particle with isospin 0 and charge -2 ? If so, why ?

My reasoning so far is:
Q=I+1/2(B+S) Q being the charge, I the isospin, B baryonic number and S strangeness.
So B+S = -4 and we cannot find any combination of quarks that verify this. The solution says a combination of 3 antiquarks c_c_c_, or  t_t_t_

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found out that the formula has been "uploaded" since the discovery of charm etc.. to yield $$ Q=I_{3}+{\frac  {1}{2}}(B+S+C+B^{\prime }+T) $$

Answer (score 1):

I would *start* with the complex conjugate of your answer, and skip the pointless Gell-Mann-Nishijima formula for the time being.

Since Q(c)=2/3=Q(t), the baryons ccc and ttt have charge 2, so their antibaryons $\bar{c}\bar{c}\bar{c} $, $\bar{t}\bar{t}\bar{t}$ have charge -2, however unstable they are.

But isospin 0 is basically a shorthand for "no light quarks", since an isosinglet diquark would have charge 1/3  so any other quark on top of it would never reach charge -2.

You may dress this up with your comment formula, so Q=0+ (-1 -3)/2, but what's the point? In this context, the G-M--N formula tells you nothing beyond what you see in quarks.

Hope springs eternal for the discovery of the charge +2 baryon [Ω<sub>ccc</sub>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2015.04.049), 
whose antiparticle you are seeking.